# how to get eclipse show a folder from file system

Tags: eclipse

i need to see a folder (svn) from file system in eclipse (is there a file explore functionality). how to achieve that?

i don't want the folder to be nested in a project. In best case eclipse links that folder to svn repository like all other projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a *Remote Systems* View that offers access to your file system.

```
Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Remote Systems -> Remote Systems
```

Comment: thx, is it possible to link it with svn (to get commit, update functionality)

Comment: @dermoritz I do not believe that this is possible.

Comment: Is this RSE? Seems that RSE is being deprecated. It doesn't come with Eclipse now, you have to install from marketplace. http://www.eclipse.org/tm/

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse: File -> New -> Project -> General -> Project ->

Untick 'default location'

Set location to the folder where your files reside you want to browse.

After pressing 'Finish' an Eclipse project is created showing all files residing in your folder

(because: creating a Eclipse project into an existing folder does not purge the files therein)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is project-centric, it will not show files or folders that are not part of a Project. You can create a link to any arbitrary location on your file system, but the link must live in a Project.

The closest thing I know of would be to install the Remote System Explorer (RSE, see http://www.eclipse.org/tm/), which offers a Local node in its Remote Systems view. But I doubt it has any integration with svn.

Answer (score 0):

open the Navigator view.... that is a view on the filesystem.

Comment: navigator only shows project folders of workspace, not other folders or files

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a folder that is a link:

```
File -> New -> Folder -> Advanced (button) -> "Link to alternate location".
```

Generally I use it to link to my localhost server (container).

Answer (score 0):

You can also alternatively right click on the file, which you want to open, you will see there `Show in Remote Systems view`. I do not know, if it is in other eclipse versions possible but I am making it with Eclipse Mars 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git, you can open Window > Perspective > Git. That will give you a Git Repositories explorer, which shows the Working Tree. The Working Tree will show all files in the filesystem, even temporary ones you created that are not added to git yet.